# Change scatter marker based on column data

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a scatter plot where the size of the marker and the marker itself vary based on column data:

```
#Get the different type of rated episodes and color
office.loc[office['scaled_ratings'] < 0.25, 'mcolor'] = 'red'
office.loc[(office['scaled_ratings'] >= 0.25) & (office['scaled_ratings'] < 0.50), 'mcolor'] = 'orange'
office.loc[(office['scaled_ratings'] >= 0.50) & (office['scaled_ratings'] < 0.75), 'mcolor'] = 'lightgreen'
office.loc[office['scaled_ratings'] >= 0.75, 'mcolor'] = 'darkgreen'

#Get episodes with guests and the marker size
office.loc[office['has_guests']== False, 'size'] = 25
office.loc[office['has_guests']== True, 'size'] = 250

#Set marker for episodes
office.loc[office['has_guests']== True, 'marker'] = '*'
office.loc[office['has_guests']== False,'marker'] = 'o'


#Create plot
plt.scatter(office['episode_number'], office['viewership_mil'], c = office['mcolor'], s= office['size'], marker= office['marker'])
```

This method of allocating columns to arguments of the function worked perfectly until I added the marker column were I get

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

I'd like to know why it doesn't work in this instance and how could I change it so that I get a specific marker based on column data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markers in scatter plots must be unique to be drawn, so a data frame can be achieved by extracting and drawing marker units. Sample data is created and graphed. See examples in the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_masked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-masked-py).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.rand(10),
                   'y': np.random.rand(10),
                   'colors': np.random.choice(['C0','C1','C2'], size=10),
                   'sizes': np.random.randint(20,70,10),
                   'symbols': np.random.choice(['*','o','^'], size=10)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for m in df['symbols'].unique():
    dff = df[df['symbols'] == m]
    ax.scatter(dff['x'], dff['y'], c=dff['colors'], s=dff['sizes'], marker=dff['symbols'].unique()[0])
plt.show()
```

[image]